# Why it failed when combining @component and bean?

Tags: spring, autowired

I am trying to use @component and regular beans. And below is my code:

**MainApp.java**

```
package com.company;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

      TextEditor te = (TextEditor) context.getBean("textEditor");

      te.spellCheck();
   }
}
```

**SpellChecker.java**

```
package com.company;

public class SpellChecker {
   public SpellChecker(){
      System.out.println("Inside SpellChecker constructor." );
   }

   public void checkSpelling(){
      System.out.println("Inside checkSpelling." );
   }
}
```

**TextEditor.java**

```
package com.company;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class TextEditor {
   @Autowired
   private SpellChecker spellChecker;
   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("region")
   private String region;

   public TextEditor() {
      System.out.println("I am in " + region );
   }

   public SpellChecker getSpellChecker( ){
      return spellChecker;
   }

   public void spellCheck(){
      spellChecker.checkSpelling();
   }
}
```

**Beans.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:annotation-config/>
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.company" />

   <bean id="spellChecker" class="SpellChecker" />

   <bean id="region" class="java.lang.String">
      <constructor-arg value="Vancouver" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

However, when I run this code, it gave error messages:

```
Cannot find class [SpellChecker] for bean with name 'spellChecker' defined in class path resource
```

When I remove the bean in the Beans.xml for SpellChecker and mark @component to it as well. Then it works (yet, the region String is still empty).

So my question is: why cannot we autowired a bean in a @Component class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't related to [Spring Integration](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/), please, choose tags properly for the questions.

You problem is that `SpellChecker` is in the `com.company` package, but `<bean class="">` really requires the fully qualified class name to define the proper class to instantiate.

The `base-package="com.company"` is exactly for the `@Component` to scan, but that fully doesn't relate to regular `<bean>` definition.

Comment: I see, thanks! BTW, do you know how to autowired a String type?

Comment: Your code looks good in that String variant. Although you may consider to use the `@Value` instead and even avoid that strange `String` bean declaration.

Answer (score 0):

By using fully qualified class name it should work... 
`<bean id="spellChecker" class="com.company.SpellChecker" />`